# MySql Query With Pivot table or Case WHEN

Tags: mysql

i need write a query with two table, maybe i need pivot query:

### First table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dataoperazione` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dataprimanota` date NOT NULL,
  `idpuntovendita` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `idoperatore` int(4) NOT NULL
)
```

---

### Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pm_azzeramentofiscale` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `idprimanota` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `cassa` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `operatore` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `azzeramento` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
)
```

---

This is my query:

```
SELECT sum(azzeramento) as incasso, p.dataprimanota as data, p.idpuntovendita 
FROM pm as p, pm_azzeramentofiscale as a 
WHERE a.idprimanota = p.id 
AND YEAR(p.dataprimanota) = 2016 
GROUP BY p.dataprimanota,p.idpuntovendita
```

the result is this format:

```
| Incasso | Data | IdPuntovendita
  1231,12 | 2015-12-12 | 3
  6211,12 | 2015-12-12 | 4
```

but i would like this format

```
| Data      | IncassoPuntovendita3 | IncassoPuntoVendita4
 2015-12-12 |   1231,12            | 6211,12
```

How can write my query ? :D

THanks Regards

Comment: You are right, you want to make a pivottable. There are no possibilities in standard sql to do this. If you have a limited and fixed numbers of IdPuntovendita, it is possible to make a sql that returns what you need, if you do not know your number of IdPuntovenditas, you will need to fetch the data and make your pivot table in some post processing.

Comment: Yes, i have limited and fixex number of Idpuntovendita.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a fixed number fo idPuntoVendita you can try this way

```
SELECT sum(case p.idpuntovendita when 3 azzeramento else 0 end) as incasso_punto_vendita3, 
       sum(case p.idpuntovendita when 4 azzeramento else 0 end) as incasso_punto_vendita34, 
       p.dataprimanota as data
FROM pm as p, pm_azzeramentofiscale as a
WHERE a.idprimanota = p.id 
AND YEAR(p.dataprimanota) = 2016 
GROUP BY p.dataprimanota,p.idpuntovendita;
```

Comment: Sorry :D  mysql reject query, it's say there is a syntax error